# Help for $\int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_y^{2 y} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x d y+\int_{\pi / 2}^\pi \int_y^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x} d x d y$

Tags: integration

Evaluate

$$\int_0^{\pi / 2} \int_y^{2 y} \frac{\sin x}{x} d x d y+\int_{\pi / 2}^\pi \int_y^\pi \frac{\sin x}{x} d x d y$$

The result can be expressed in SinIntegral Si(x).

But this question appeared in the basic calculus exam, so I believe there exists another exact solution.

For example: The first term, we can obtain the result by changing the order of integration.

$$\int_0^\pi \int_{x / 2}^x \frac{\sin x}{x} d y d x=1$$

So~ does anyone have good idea about this problem.

Comment: If you use a series solution, you will end with $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\,\frac{ \pi ^{2 n+2}}{2 \Gamma (2 n+3)}$  which is $1$

Answer (score 1):

The main idea is to sketch the region of both double integrals in the same graph. I will use desmos here, but you could do it on paper as well:
[image: Sketch of the region]

The first integral's region describes the "yellow" part. The second integral's region describes the "blue part". Since you are adding them, and they have the same function $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$, then we can describe the sum of these two regions as a single  equivalent region, namely, as the blue arrow indicates, from  $y=\frac{x}{2}$ to $y=x$ ,and from $x=0$ to $x=\pi$.

Let $I$ be the sum of the two given integrals (I.e. the problem).
Hence, the sum of the two integrals becomes the following integral:
$$ I= \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}}\int_{y}^{2y}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dxdy+\int_{\frac{\pi}{2}}^{\pi}\int_{y}^{\pi}\frac{sin(x)}{x}dxdy=\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{\frac{x}{2}}^{x}\frac{sin(x)}{x} dydx $$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}x*\frac{sin(x)}{x} dx $$
$$\implies I=\int_{0}^{\pi}\frac{1}{2}sin(x)dx$$
$$\implies I=-\frac{1}{2}cos(\pi)+\frac{1}{2}cos(0)$$
$$\implies I= \frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}=1$$

Confirmation of the answer using WolframAlpha:

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i2d=true&i=Integrate%5BDivide%5Bsin%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2C2y%7D%2C%7By%2C0%2CDivide%5Bpi%2C2%5D%7D%5D%2BIntegrate%5BDivide%5Bsin%5C%2840%29x%5C%2841%29%2Cx%5D%2C%7Bx%2Cy%2Cpi%7D%2C%7By%2CDivide%5Bpi%2C2%5D%2Cpi%7D%5D